# Symfony2 Twig date("H") "Military Time"

Tags: php, date, symfony, twig

I have an application in Symfony where when  a user posts a comment, the comment's creation time is stored. Then, it is converted to the correct format with twig, like so:

```
{{ comment.created|date('m-d-Y H:i:s a') }}
```

The only problem is, if the user submitted the comment at 4 P.M., it comes up as 16 P.M.

I'd like it to just show 4 P.M.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `h` instead of `H`

```
{{ comment.created|date('m-d-Y h:i:s a') }}
```

From: https://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> h 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
>
> H 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros